# How to disable nagging "try edge" notifications?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notifications, microsoft-edge

Every so often (ranging from a few days to a few hours between events) when I am using Chrome, Windows pops up a notification giving me some stupid reason to use Microsoft Edge instead of Chrome.  There are several different versions of the notification, the two most common ones I have gotten claim that Chrome is draining my battery or Chrome is slower than Edge.

This is driving me absolutely crazy, I like Chrome (a lot) better than Edge, not just because of the numerous security flaws in Edge's history.  But that doesn't matter, I don't want my OS telling me *once* to prefer one program over another, let alone *constantly* nagging me.

These notifications are special in that the disable notification option is grayed out when I right-click the notification.  Is there any way I can silence these annoying notifications?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any way I can silence these annoying notifications?

You just disable them:

1. Launch the `Settings` App
2. Search for `Notifications & Actions`
3. Disable the notifications by setting `Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows` to **Off**

[image]

Comment: That's a nice short answer, but I think it would be even more helpful if it described the way to show this setting.

Comment: Yes, and it's not in Edge's settings. ;-)

Comment: Ok, if you think this is clear... Sorry about taking your time.

Comment: I agree with @palsch.  While I personally know how to get here, probably not everyone will.  Unless someone knows their way around Windows 10 really well I don't think most people would not consider it very "obvious" that this is not in Edge's interface or recognize this as "clearly" from the settings app at all, let alone where in settings to find Notifications and actions.

Comment: I will think about updating the screenshot, its unlikely to happen though, because the screenshot illistrates what I want it to illistrate and I already spent 5 minutes santizing the image.

Comment: For a bigger screenshot https://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/turn-off-windows-10s-pushy-edge-notifications/

Answer (score -3):

1-Click windows Start Button
2-Start typing "Get tips, tricks and suggestions as you use windows"
3-Press Enter
4-Turn Off 'Get tips, tricks and suggestions as you use windows' setting
5-Enjoy

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but if you look a bit closer you will see that your answer is almost exactly the same as the one that was previously accepted.